# MongoDB - Failed to import JSON data using mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb

Hello guys I'm trying to import JSON file to my collection in mongodb database but keeps give me an error. how to import this json file?
I tried using mongodb compass and mongoshell give me this error

```
E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :      
@(shell):1:14
```

This is the file: https://github.com/pedox/indonesia-mongo/blob/master/indonesia.json

My mongoimport command:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db DB_Pro --collection indonesia --file:C:\Users\<usernamePC>\Downloads\db indonesia\Indonesia-mongo\indonesia.json
```

Comment: Use the command-line tool `mongoimport` to import JSON data in to a MongoDB collection. It is  run from the operating system command line / terminal / command prompt.

Comment: @prasad_I got an error `2020-07-02T11:23:47.375+0700 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :      
@(shell):1:14`

Comment: Please edit your post and include the mongoimport command you are using.

Comment: `--file:C:\Users\...` instead try this: `--file="C:\Users\..."`

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal in the folder your `.json` file is located in. Here is one I do to import the data in `Ubuntu`.

1. Open a folder and `Open in terminal`
2. Download the file:

   ```
   curl -o data.json https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pedox/indonesia-mongo/master/indonesia.json
   ```
3. Import the file:

   ```
   mongoimport --host=localhost --port=27017 --username=gotqn --collection=trades --db=github --file=data.json --authenticationDatabase admin
   ```

So, I need to specify the `host` and the `port`. Also, because I am using a password to authenticated I need to specify the `username` and the `authenticationDatabase` and then enter the password when asked.

Also, as there are various options - check the [official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Comment: i tried but this error i always got `MongoDB Enterprise > mongoimport --jsonArray --db DB_Pro --collection indonesia --file=C:\Users\sekti\Downloads\db indonesia\Indonesia-mongo\indonesia.json
2020-07-02T12:56:05.226+0700 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :      
@(shell):1:14`

Comment: @sekti92uk leave the mongodb console, open new terminal

Comment: @sekti92uk You are running the import command from the `mongo` shell. You need to run the import from operating system command prompt (I had already mentioned that in my earlier comments). Also, place the _file path_ in quotes - because you have a space in the path `...\db indonesia\...`.

Comment: @prasad_ I did on mongoshell but still no luck, I have to insert it as document now is  working. Thanks for the help. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using Studio3t. it is very user friendly to use MongoDB and provides many functionalities to operate on db and collections

Comment: what's make that different with mongodb compass?

Comment: https://stackshare.io/stackups/mongodb-compass-vs-studio-3t